# Multiplying Numpy/Scipy Sparse and Dense Matrices Efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working to implement the following equation:

```
X =(Y.T * Y + Y.T * C * Y) ^ -1
```

Y is a (n x f) matrix and C is (n x n) diagonal one; n is about 300k and f will vary between 100 and 200. As part of an optimization process this equation will be used almost 100 million times so it has to be processed really fast.

Y is initialized randomly and C is a very sparse matrix with only a few numbers out of the 300k on the diagonal will be different than 0.Since Numpy's diagonal functions creates dense matrices, I created C as a sparse csr matrix. But when trying to solve the first part of the equation:

```
r = dot(C, Y)
```

The computer crashes due Memory limits. I decided then trying to convert Y to csr_matrix and make the same operation:

```
r = dot(C, Ysparse)
```

and this approach took **1.38 ms**. But this solution is somewhat "tricky" since I'm using a sparse matrix to store a dense one, I wonder how efficient this really.

So my question is if is there some way of multiplying the sparse C and the dense Y without having to turn Y into sparse and improve performance? If somehow C could be represented as diagonal dense without consuming tons of memory maybe this would lead to very efficient performance but I don't know if this is possible.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: just out of curiosity: Is this for a recommender system? (e.g. http://bit.ly/1aqCsfs)

Comment: @TobiasDomhan yes, I was working on implementing Koren's paper on implicit feedback datasets =).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The reason the dot product runs into memory issues when computing r = dot(C,Y) is because numpy's dot function does not have native support for handling sparse matrices. What is happening is numpy thinks of the sparse matrix C as a python object, and not a numpy array. If you inspect on small scale you can see the problem first hand:

```
>>> from numpy import dot, array
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> Y = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> C = sparse.csr_matrix(array([[1,0], [0,2]]))
>>> dot(C,Y)
array([[  (0, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    2,   (0, 0) 2
  (1, 1)    4],
  [  (0, 0) 3
  (1, 1)    6,   (0, 0) 4
  (1, 1)    8]], dtype=object)
```

Clearly the above is not the result you are interested in. Instead what you want to do is compute using scipy's sparse.csr_matrix.dot function:

```
r = sparse.csr_matrix.dot(C, Y)
```

or more compactly

```
r = C.dot(Y)
```

Comment: Since this is a school project, let me point out that "being compact" shouldn't be a goal. However, your second example *is* the more Object-Oriented approach, and, of course, the better approach to take in general. But it's not about being short. Being readable is far more important than being brief.

Comment: I was mostly posting since I had to deal with the same problem on that day and did not see an explanation for WHY the dot(sparse, dense) function was not returning the result you were expecting. Just hoping to give someone assistance if they run into this problem themselves.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

f = 100
n = 300000

Y = np.random.rand(n, f)
Cdiag = np.random.rand(n) # diagonal of C
Cdiag[np.random.rand(n) < 0.99] = 0

# Compute Y.T * C * Y, skipping zero elements
mask = np.flatnonzero(Cdiag)
Cskip = Cdiag[mask]

def ytcy_fast(Y):
    Yskip = Y[mask,:]
    CY = Cskip[:,None] * Yskip  # broadcasting
    return Yskip.T.dot(CY)

%timeit ytcy_fast(Y)

# For comparison: all-sparse matrices
C_sparse = sparse.spdiags([Cdiag], [0], n, n)
Y_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(Y)
%timeit Y_sparse.T.dot(C_sparse * Y_sparse)
```

My timings:

```
In [59]: %timeit ytcy_fast(Y)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit Y_sparse.T.dot(C_sparse * Y_sparse)
1 loops, best of 3: 282 ms per loop
```

Comment: Tnx for the help! I tried it and I got roughly the same timings. For now the best solution is to indeed represent the dense Y as a sparse and then it goes faster. Maybe there's no way on how to improve this

Comment: this is a great solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

First, are you really sure you need to perform a full matrix inversion in your problem ? Most of the time, one only really need to compute x = A^-1 y which is a much easier problem to solve.

If this is really so, I would consider computing an approximation of the inverse matrix instead of the full matrix inversion. Since matrix inversion is *really* costly. See for example the [Lanczos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm) for an efficient approximation of the inverse matrix. The approximation can be stored sparsely as a bonus. Plus, it requires only matrix-vector operations so you don't even have to store the full matrix to inverse.

As an alternative, using pyoperators, you can also use to .todense method to compute the matrix to inverse using efficient matrix vector operations. There is a special sparse container for diagonal matrices.

For an implementation of the Lanczos algorithm, you can have a look at [pyoperators](https://github.com/pchanial/pyoperators) (disclaimer: I am one of the coauthor of this piece of software).

Comment: Tnx for this information, I'll study it for sure! In this problem the inversion process hasn't been too much costly, it's taking 258 us here (for a 100 x 100 matrix if f = 100). If I can further reduce this time it would be great since it will repeat several million times. The main bottleneck is the 1.38 ms from the multiplication which would take days to finish. I'll take a look at pyoperators and try it out! Tnx!

Comment: I made some bench on your pb and it looks like the longest matrix vector operation is Y.T * v. Is your diagonal matrix by any chance positive-definite ? This would allow to write the problem as (B.T * B)^-1 with B = sqrt(C) * Y. Also in the 100 million uses, is C varying or Y ?

Comment: Good point, I'm not sure if C is indeed a positive-definite matrix, I don't think so (I have to study more this subject, I'm following Koren's paper and he didn't mention this). C is constant and in this process so is Y. Y will change only when all Xu were calculated, then Y updating process begins.

Comment: Since C is diagonal if all element are >0, it is positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was possible when the question was asked; but nowadays, broadcasting is your friend. An n*n diagonal matrix needs only be an array of the diagonal elements to be used in a matrix product:

```
>>> n, f = 5, 3
>>> Y = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, f))
>>> C = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n,))
>>> Y.shape
(5, 3)
>>> C.shape
(5,)
>>> np.all(Y.T @ np.diag(C) @ Y == Y.T*C @ Y)
True
```

Do note that `Y.T*C @ Y` is non-associative:

```
>>> Y.T*(C @ Y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5) (3,)
```

But `Y.T @ (C[:, np.newaxis]*Y)` would yield the expected result:

```
>>> np.all(Y.T*C @ Y == Y.T@(C[:, np.newaxis]*Y))
True
```