# How to do efficient matrix multiplication between a dense numpy matrix and a sparse scipy vector?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Multiplying a dense numpy matrix with a sparse scipy vector using `@` is incredibly inefficient . It seems like it doesn't make use of the sparsity of the vector at all.

Say we have

```
A = np.eye(5000)
x = np.eye(5000)[333]
x = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(x).T # make it a sparse vector
```

Then multiplication using `@` yields:

```
%timeit A @ x
8 ms ± 78.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Let's write an incredibly crappy sparse multiplication ourselves:

```
def mult_dense_with_sparse(A, x):
  return (A[:,x.nonzero()[0]] @ x.toarray()[x.nonzero()[0]]).T[0]
```

Lo and behold:

```
%timeit mult_dense_with_sparse(A, x)
50.3 µs ± 45.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

It's **much** faster! Even though this implementation first creates a dense vector by adding all the zeros again, and then removes all the zeros again... So I'm wondering, if not `@`, how can I multiply a dense numpy matrix with a sparse scipy vector efficiently? Surely such a basic operation is part of scipy?

Edit: provided solution in other question is not helpful as it is just as inefficient as `@`:

```
%timeit scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot(A, x)
7.97 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Edit 2 in responaw Hameer Abbasi:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   101                                                       @profile
   102                                                       def ratio(self, n):
   103        80         51.0      0.6      0.0                  s = n + 1
   104        80   11401854.0 142523.2     16.1                  self.sfpc = self.scolPCA(s) # sparse first principal component
   106        80     351898.0   4398.7      0.5                  wSums = (self.signals[:,self.sfpc.nonzero()[0]] @ self.sfpc.toarray()[self.sfpc.nonzero()[0]]).T[0]
   108        80   56487433.0 706092.9     79.7                  wSums = self.sfpc.T.dot(self.signals.T)[0]
   110        80    2521189.0  31514.9      3.6                  self.Flag, self.threshold, self.incline, self.deltaVar = self.actFunctOpt(list(wSums))
   111        80        160.0      2.0      0.0                  return  self.deltaVar / (2 + s)
```

Here you can see that our 'hack' takes about 0.5% of the time of this function, while using `dot` takes 79.7% of the time in this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying Numpy/Scipy Sparse and Dense Matrices Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272453/multiplying-numpy-scipy-sparse-and-dense-matrices-efficiently)

Comment: I provided an edit showing that `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot` is just as inefficient in the case of matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: If the result is a dense array, the sparse matrix has first been converted to an array (.toarray()).  Only `sparse*sparse` returns sparse, using scipy.sparse's own code.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `A` is of type `np.ndarray`, and `x` is of type `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`.

If you're looking for the simplest answer possible to speed this up, here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
A = np.random.rand(5000, 5000)
v = np.zeros((5000, 1))
v[333] = 1
v_s = sps.csc_matrix(v)
%timeit v_s.T.dot(A).T # 46.6 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit A @ v # 6.75 ms ± 29.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

However, if you want to get the mechanics behind this answer: Currently, the operator `@` doesn't support overloading for a NumPy array due to a [bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9028). Also, `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` doesn't even *try* to override `@`, and matrix multiplication is faster for `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` (`coo_matrix` will first be converted to `csr_matrix` for multiplication anyway).

So what happens is NumPy converts your sparse vector into a NumPy array, then performs dense multiplication.

However, `csr_matrix.dot` exists and supports multiplication with dense NumPy arrays. So we use the property `A @ B = (B.T @ A.T).T`, along with the fact that `csc_matrix.T` produces `csr_matrix` to produce the above optimised code.

Comment: Please see my edit. Using `dot` is still very inefficient in our case.

Comment: Looks like `@` is working right when used with sparse matrices.  `sparse@sparse` is the same as `sparse*sparse`, the sparse matrix product.  `sparse@dense` is the same as `sparse.A@dense` but a bit faster. For some reason `dense@sparse` is slower.  `dense.dot(sparse)` is still wrong.

Comment: @Alex This is a general thing. Usually, the more general code is, the more slow it is. `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot` is an example of general code. Your code is specialised, and therefore faster.